# Problems with axios and useState in React App

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to fetch data with axios, I use console.log and it's seem worked fine. But when I try to set it to my state, it's return an empty array. I'm tried to searching my problem but have no luck. Any idea?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Error from '../components/Error';

export const PhotoContext = React.createContext();

const apiKey = '636e1481b4f3c446d26b8eb6ebfe7127';

const PhotoContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const runSearch = (query) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${apiKey}&tags=${query}&per_page=24&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setImages(response.data.photos.photo);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(images); //return an empty array
        console.log(response.data.photos.photo); // return an object as it should be
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return <Error />;
      });
  };
  return (
    <PhotoContext.Provider value={{ images, loading, runSearch }}>
      {props.children}
    </PhotoContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default PhotoContextProvider;
```

Here's my full code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hhqiwr?file=context%2FPhotoContext.tsx

Comment: What purpose do your `console.log()` lines serve? Did you need those particular pieces of data logged for some reason? Was the rest of your app not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, setting of state is async, if you console.log `images` after using `setImages`, it will return the old value.

The correct way is to use `useEffect` to monitor changes.

```
useEffect(() => {

  console.log('images', images) //new value will be reflected

},[images])
```

I've checked your codesandbox and it is setting the state correctly for `response.data.photos.photo`

Comment: Setting state is in fact synchronous. What it cannot do is update the state value in an already declared variable until the next render.

Comment: Partly right @Phil https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous It's not immediate and it's non-blocking, hence it's async

Comment: I'm not sure that applies to the `useState` hook since each of those would be tracked individually. I suppose multiple calls to the same _setter_ may be batched. I just think it's incorrect to say that setting state is asynchronous. It's the render cycle that provides delays between writing a value and being able to read it

Comment: @babamama Add a conditional check (for undefine values) before you use `setImages`